# SQL query need to get user where program column includes certain program

Tags: sql, select, count

Let me try to explain this to the best of my ability:

I have a table in which there is a userID column and a program column (along with other columns of non importance). I need to find the users within this table that have multiple instances within this table where that user has a program of X associated with it.

Can anyone help me please?

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
            WPP.USERID 
        FROM 
            WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
        INNER JOIN 
            WEBPROGRAMS WP 
        ON 
            WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
        WHERE 
            CONFIRMED = 1 AND 
            WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') AND 
            WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2000-01-01' AND 
            WPP.PROGRAMCODE = 'CL2010'
        GROUP BY 
            WPP.USERID 
        HAVING 
            COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Program VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Program = 'X'

SELECT UserID, COUNT(Program) Duplicates
FROM Table
WHERE Program = @Program
AND COUNT(Program) > 1
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all your missing is group by wpp.programcode has well

```
SELECT 
                        WPP.USERID 
                FROM 
                        WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
                INNER JOIN 
                        WEBPROGRAMS WP 
                ON 
                        WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
                WHERE 
                        CONFIRMED = 1 AND 
                        WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') AND 
                        WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2000-01-01' AND 
                        WPP.PROGRAMCODE = 'CL2010'
                GROUP BY 
                        WPP.USERID , WPP.PROGRAMCODE
                HAVING 
                        COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) > 1
```

If you don't want to limit it to programcode cl2010 drop it from the where clause.  I would also add wpp.programcode to you select list so you can see what codes are duplicated and count(wpp.programcode) if you want to see how many times.

Comment: I need the programcode of CL2010 because I am trying to find those users who have attanded mutliple programs including that program

Comment: That's fine but it will also limit you to that program

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to do this as a subquery since once you add in a where clause limiting your results to a specific program type you will only be able to find participants who have multiple rows of that program type.  You are probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 
    WPP.USERID 
FROM 
    WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
INNER JOIN 
    WEBPROGRAMS WP ON WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
WHERE 
    CONFIRMED = 1 AND 
    WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1') AND 
    WP.PROGRAMSTARTDATE >= '2000-01-01' AND 
    WPP.PROGRAMCODE = 'CL2010'
    WPP.USERID IN (
        SELECT 
            WPP.USERID
        FROM
            WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP
        GROUP BY 
            WPP.USERID 
        HAVING 
            COUNT(WPP.PROGRAMCODE) > 1)
GROUP BY
    WPP.USERID
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion out, however,  it is returning more than expected

Comment: What do you mean returning more than expected?  Multiple USERID's returned or USERIDS that don't match your criteria?  I think you are probably having the first error, and I can see why I'm updating to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume it's not finding any duplicates even though you know them to exist.  With your query, if your duplicate has a different type, code, or start date before 2000-1-1, then those records will be filtered out before you run your count.  Keep in mind that it's going to apply the "where" pretty early on in the process.

Keep this processing order in mind: http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html